# In Crystal Reports, I'm looking to only have one Business with results to show on my report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report that shows all businesses that have results completed in a selected time frame.
I want to have this report only show 1 business because this separate report is strictly for them.

Where do I go about updating the "Group #1 Name: Customers.Business" to only show "BusinessA"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the menu options of ***Report, Selection Formulas, Record...***
to enter a filter condition such as

```
{Customer.Business} = "Business A"
```

Comment: Thank you. 

The query went through but now my Report is blank.
These are the queries that are in that Record Selection. 

datevalue ({Sample.DateCompleted}) >= {@StartDate}
AND datevalue({Sample.DateCompleted}) <={@EndDate }
AND {Customers.Business} = "Business A"

Comment: "Business A" is just an example. You need to use YOUR value.

Comment: Yes, I know "Business A" was an example. Here is the actual query I have in the report. 

datevalue ({Sample.DateCompleted}) >= {@StartDate} AND datevalue({Sample.DateCompleted}) <={@EndDate } AND {Customers.Business} = "AmeriWater, Inc"

Comment: Isolate the issue. 
Remove the condition and see if any row shows that field as having EXACTLY that value.